# How can I replace keys in to_json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am overriding `to_json`.

When I call `to_json` on my model I get the following:

```
{ "integer1": "23", "integer2": "2", "integer3": "4", ... }
```

I want `to_json` to return:

```
{ "Something": "23", "SomethingElse": "2", "AnotherThing": "4", ... }
```

I have an array that contains the key and its mapping:

```
"integer1" => "Something", "integer2" => "SomethingElse", "integer3" => "AnotherThing", ....
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: That last is not an array, it's a Hash, right?

Comment: @Phrogz, well its actually an object that contains that info.

Comment: @c0deNinja so you have an object, that you called an array, and showed as a hash? Consider that imprecise details like this make it hard to help you.

Comment: @Phrogz, sorry about that, but i can turn the object into a hash, or anything else as needed.  Didn't think the object mattered as long as i could create a mapping as i showed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Convert your [model instance into a hash](http://snippets.dzone.com/tag/to_hash)
2. Convert the hash into what you want:

   ```
   h1 = { "integer1" => "23", "integer2" => "2", "integer3" => "4" }
   h2 = { "integer1" => "Something", "integer2" => "SomethingElse", "integer3" => "AnotherThing" }
   desired = Hash[ h1.map{ |k,v| [ h2[k], v ] } ]
   ```
3. Get your JSON from that:

   ```
   json = desired.to_json
   ```

Comment: As an alternate you could do `Hash[h2.values.zip(h1.values)]` or `Hash[h2.values_at(*h1.keys).zip(h1.values)]` if there's a chance the Hash entries would be inserted in different orders.

Answer (score 3):

I highly advocate using [draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) or a similar decorator-pattern solution to create "JSON views" of objects.

You would have a decorator for your model, on which you define `def as_json(options = {})` and return a hash of the data you want to use as the JSON representation of your model. This decouples it from the model, and lets you modify the "data view" of the model separately from the internal representation of the data easily.